# Ambiguous call with list_of in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, compiler-errors

I am trying to convert a projet from VS2008 to 2010 but am hitting  problem because of added move constructors (and probably the fact that there are nested list_of's here). The following code snippet shows the error (in the actual code these constructs are used to initialise some statics):

```
enum some_enum {R, G, B};

typedef std::pair<some_enum, some_enum> Enum_Pair;
typedef std::vector<some_enum> Enum_list;
typedef std::pair<Enum_Pair, Enum_list> Some_Struct;
typedef std::list<Some_Struct> Full_Struct;

#define MAKEFULLSTRUCT(First_, Second_, some_enums)\
    (Some_Struct(Enum_Pair(First_, Second_), list_of (some_enums) ))

int main()
{
    int i = G;
    Full_Struct test_struct = list_of
        MAKEFULLSTRUCT(R, R, R).to_container(test_struct);
}
```

which leads to

```
error C2668: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
with  [_Ty=some_enum]
vector(593): could be 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(std::vector<_Ty> &&)'
with  [ _Ty=some_enum]
vector(515): or       'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned int)'
with  [ _Ty=some_enum]
while trying to match the argument list '(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>)'
with  [ T=some_enum ]
```

Is there some way to resolve this while still using boost::list_of? Or do I have to switch to another initialisation mechanism?

Comment: What version of boost do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Boost.Assign. The return type of `list_of` has a generic conversion to type `T` without trying to constrain `T` at all. Hence, either `std::vector` constructor -- the one that takes a `std::vector &&` and the one that takes an `unsigned int` -- is equally good, leading to the ambiguity.

The work-around for you would be to use `convert_to_container`, as follows:

```
#define MAKEFULLSTRUCT(First_, Second_, some_enums)\
    (Some_Struct(Enum_Pair(First_, Second_), \
        list_of(some_enums).convert_to_container<Enum_list>()))
```