# Ambiguity when using boost::assign::list_of to construct a std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

This code:

```
std::vector<int>(boost::assign::list_of<int>(1)(2)(3));
```

gives the error:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void <unnamed>::RequestHandler::processRequest(Foo&, Bar, unsigned int, unsigned int*, const char*, boost::shared_ptr<Baz::IOutput>&)':
main.cpp:450: error: call of overloaded 'vector(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>&)' is ambiguous
/4.4.2/bits/stl_vector.h:241: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/4.4.2/bits/stl_vector.h:227: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_t, const _Tp&, const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/4.4.2/bits/stl_vector.h:215: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
```

when compiled for gcc 4.4.2.

How can I revolve this issue? Ultimately I'm trying to compile the following:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

typedef boost::variant<vector<bool>, vector<int>, vector<string> > Container;

vector<pair<string, Container > > v =
            list_of(pair<string, Container >("Scotland",Container(vector<int>(list_of<int>(1)(2)(3)))))
            (pair<string, Container >("Sweden",Container()));
```

This fails for the same reason.

My application involves setting up data structures for the purposes of unit testing. I want the initialization to be clear rather that having to do lots of push_backs etc.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a fix:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Container > > v =
    boost::assign::list_of(std::pair<std::string, Container >("Scotland",Container(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3).convert_to_container<std::vector<int> >())))
    (std::pair<std::string, Container >("Sweden",Container()));
```

This is so ugly. What might I do to make this clearer. My unit tests are written only in header files so I don't use `using namespace`.

Comment: `typedef`s (or C++11 `using`) do wonders for readability.

Comment: @rubenvb Hope its easier to read now...

Comment: Just a side note, don't use vector<bool>. It's specialized to act like a bitset but I believe it has many problems.

"Effective STL," Item 18, Scott Meyers discourages use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dupe of [Ambiguous call with list_of in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352692/ambiguous-call-with-list-of-in-vs2010/12362548#12362548). Boost.Assign was written targeting the C++03 standard library. Things changed in C++11 and Boost.Assign hasn't been updated. The bug report is [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7364).